# How can I resolve HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

Currently, I have a problem in download data from google cloud storage. Here is the error: `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)`

Although I increase the timeout to 600 -> The error still shows 60. Here is my code:

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILENAME)
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

blob = bucket.blob('blob_name')
blob.download_to_filename('dest_name', timeout=600)
```

Moreover, I also changed the `timeout` as a tuple (connect_timeout, read_timeout)
`blob.download_to_filename('dest_name', timeout=(600, 600))`
but, It still not working.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: The code is OK. I have used it on my side and it's working fine. Were do you run this?

Comment: Hi, I run it on my server.

Comment: I executed this on my side in cloud vm - everything works fine.... not sure what to ask more... can you try on different machine?

Comment: Ran into the same problem while making `blob.download_as_bytes()` request from docker container, when the same python script works outside docker.